# Symfony2 assetic:dump | error Output: "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: java, symfony, assetic, yui-compressor

I downloaded [yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/releases) and placed it in `app/Resources/java/` folder.

Next I created the `{% stylesheets %}` block in my twig template as in example below:

```
{% stylesheets 
    'bundles/arsen/css/style.css'
    filter='cssrewrite, yui_css'
    output='assets/css/complied.css'
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

When I run `app/console assetic:dump`, I get this error:

```
  "/usr/bin/java" "-jar" "C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony27\app/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar" "--charset" "UTF-8" "-o" "C:\Users\SYMFONY\AppData\Local\Temp\ass2341.tmp" "--type" "css" "C:\Users\SYMFONY\AppData\Local\Temp\ass2340.tmp"
  Error Output:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  The system cannot find the path specified.
```

As far I know, I have java jre installed and I have access to java from command line:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And in my windows path I have:
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath registered
This path points here:
[image]

Paths looks fine to me.
Does anyone know what is missing or where is the issue preventing `app/console assetic:dump` command  from working?

Perhaps this setting causes the issue `app/config/config.yml`:

```
assetic:
    #...
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        yui_css:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar"
            #...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by symfony documentation :

> Windows users need to remember to update config to proper Java location.
>   In Windows7 x64 bit by default it's C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe.

Actually, the command is looking for an executable located in `/usr/bin/java` which doesn't exist on Windows.

Also, you have to register your java path in your assetic configuration :

```
assetic:
    # ...
    java: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
```

See the [YUI Compressor](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/yuicompressor.html#configure-the-yui-filters) part of documentation.